# Eclipse tooltip on Ubuntu 22.04 is always empty

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and Eclipse IDE (09.22). Every time I show the tooltip (for javadocs or so) it's just empty. I've seen people talking about similar problem and one of these solutions is to install gnome-color-chooser but I'm worried color-chooser is not right for jammy (Ubuntu 22.04) : I tried to install the deb but there are too many dependencies to be installed (who need dependencies on their own). Does anyone have the same issue? or know how to solve it? thank you.

[image]

Comment: Check your Colors and Fonts preference page for "javadoc" and "hover" values. Are you sure what you're hovering over has JavaDoc known to Eclipse and your project?

Comment: I checked, it doesn't seem a font problem. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This issue almost made eclipse unusable for me.
In my case i am on X11 not Wayland, which i think is relevant.  Anyway, set this variable before starting eclipse e.g.

`WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 ./eclipse`

Another issue this fixes is the welcome screen (Help -> Welcome) was blank.

When running eclipse from the console, every time i hovered over something, i would get an empty dialog, and this error in the console

> WebKitWebProcess:1211824): Gdk-ERROR **: 17:31:08.234: The program 'WebKitWebProcess' received an X Window System error.
> This probably reflects a bug in the program.
> The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
> (Details: serial 178 error_code 2 request_code 151 (GLX) minor_code 34)

Comment: This works for me! Thanks!
Funny note: Until last week all worked normal without this "workaround". Today eclipse broke and need to start with this workaround. Always grate to see how fast all broke down to death until its unusable...

Comment: Your solution worked in my Ubuntu 22.04.2. A few days ago all was good. Hard to find out what Linux package update to blame.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that just changing the theme fixed the issue under Gnome 44.1/Wayland. I've been unable to reproduce it since. So this is not related to Wayland or Xorg as suggested above. You can safely just change the theme/palette and then revert it back to what it was.

UPDATE: the issue returns in an unpredictable manner. The fix is the same. Unchecking "Enable theming" might be a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching themes to `Dark` with `Reduced Palette`.

I was getting this as well when using the `Dark` theme with `Default` color and font configuration. But I switched the color/font configuration to `Reduced Palette` and the tooltip started working! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after installing libwebkitgtk. In my case I ran `sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-6.0-dev`, although I don't know if it is required -dev.

Comment: Ignore, it is still failing.